Difference between 以外に and 以外は, 他に and 他は
I read on one forum that the difference between 以外は and 以外に is that:

以外は is used as a subject and the subject doesn't need to do anything - 山田さん以外は、学校に行く必要があります。Everyone needs to go to school, except Yamada.
以外に is used as an adverb and adds something to something else - 山田さん以外に、マリアさんも学校に行く必要があります。Besides Yamada, Marina-san also needs to go to school.

So, my question is:

Is the information I described correct? and
So what about the difference between 他に and 他は, could there be the same differences as with 以外に and 以外は?


"必要あります" is incorrect, you should say "必要があります".

Let's think about this in the following way:
"山田さん以外" is basically a noun phrase that means "someone/people other than Yamada" or "everyone but Yamada". Whether it refers to "someone (singular)" or "everyone/people (plural)" depends on the context. You can attach any particle as long as it makes sense, including を and に:

山田さん以外を招待した。
I invited everyone but Yamada.
山田さん以外にそれを伝えた。
I told it to people other than Yamada.
山田さん以外にお願いしてください。
Please ask someone who is not Yamada.
山田さん以外から聞いた。
I heard it from someone other than Yamada.

However, 山田さん以外に at the beginning of a sentence has an additional usage: "Besides Yamada" or "In addition to Yamada". You need to remember this usage as an exception. This is technically an adverb, but more precisely, it's a disjunct (also known as a sentence adverb).
他【ほか】 is very similar. Basically, it's a noun that means "others", "someone else", or "everyone else", depending on the context. You can attach any particle to it:

他を招待した。
I invited the others.
他にお願いしてください。
Please ask some other person/company.
他から聞いた。
I heard it from someone else.

But ～の他に also works as a disjunct:

山田さんの他に、マリアさんも学校に行く必要があります。
Besides Yamada, Maria also needs to go to school.
Not only Yamada but also Maria needs to go to wchool.


so, returning to these examples - 山田さん以外は、学校に行く必要があります。Everyone needs to go to school, except Yamada.. and 山田さん以外に、マリアさんも学校に行く必要があります。Besides Yamada, Marina-san also needs to go to school. . も changes the sentence here, or に　and は are so different? if you understand the difference I'm talking about - first - everyone except Y. second - besides Y, someone else is going.

@saenai As I explained in my answer, X以外に has a special function.

so, 山田さん以外に、学校に行く必要があります (Everyone needs to go to school, except Yamada..)　is corrent?
